# Simple MVC - Displaying a Customer

Tags: java, mvc

I would like to ask about possible improvement of this code. I have created very simple code using MVC pattern. Is there any logic or anything to change? I tried to keep MVC idea.

This is **model**, class `Customer`:

```
package customereditor;    

public class Customer {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

This is **view**, class `CustomerView`:

```
package customereditor;

public class CustomerView {

    public void displayCustomer(int customerID, String customerName, String customerSurname) {

        System.out.println("ID: " + customerID);
        System.out.println("Name: " + customerName);
        System.out.println("Surname: " + customerSurname);
    }

}
```

This is **controller**, class `CustomerController`:

```
package customereditor;    

public class CustomerController {

    Customer model;
    CustomerView view;

    public CustomerController(Customer model, CustomerView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
       model.setID(customerID);
    }

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return model.getID();
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
       model.setName(customerName);
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return model.getName();
    }

    public void setCustomerSurname(String customerSurname) {
       model.setSurname(customerSurname);
    }

    public String getCustomerSurname() {
        return model.getSurname();
    }

    public void displayCustomer() {        
        view.displayCustomer(model.getID(),model.getName(),model.getSurname());
    }

}
```

And this is **class with main method**, class `MainCustomer`:

```
package customereditor;

public class MainCustomer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer model = new Customer();
        CustomerView view = new CustomerView();
        CustomerController controller = new CustomerController(model, view);        

        controller.setCustomerID(1);
        controller.setCustomerName("John");
        controller.setCustomerSurname("Doe");
        controller.displayCustomer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is not MVC. It's DataVC, this results in some minor and major design problems.

#### Unwrapping data in the Controller

That's the first really bad idea here. You're trying to hide the way Data is structured from the View, based on the assumption that the Model is the Data.

That's not the case. Just pass your `Customer`-instance to the View for display. The **view** knows what it needs from the Customer to display it properly.
The Controller **doesn't**.

#### Model != POJO

The Model in an MVC application is **not** the "Domain Model". It's instead the Layer to provide instances of classes modelling that Domain Model (in your case Customers).

Instead of having the Controller **receiving** a Customer from the calling code (which is unsustainable in larger applications), you should make the Controller ask the Model for customers depending on user-input.

#### More nitpicks

- Your package-declaration should hint at a domain you own.
- Making the Customer's field accessible through getters on the Controller is a dumb idea. The Controller doesn't actually have to know about the internals of Customers and shouldn't be asked about them